# showing tag style attribute in phpstorm

Tags: phpstorm

I'm currently trying phpstorm ide 6 . When I open a html file where I have a div like this

```
<div style="height:20px;background-color:red;"><!-- --></div>
```

the editor is showing me something like this:

```
<div style="..."><!-- --></div>
```

If I mouse over/click the style attribute it shows me the content. It there a way I can setup this to always show me the style content?

Thanks

**SOLUTION FOUND:
File -> Settings -> Editor -> Code folding -> unckeck HTML 'style' attribute**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I already found the solution
UPDATE: Newer versions(as mention by @gArn)

> File -> Settings -> Editor -> **General ->** Code folding -> unckeck
>   HTML 'style' attribute

Older versions:

> File -> Settings -> Editor -> Code folding -> unckeck HTML 'style'
>   attribute

Comment: In newer versions it seems to be: `File -> Settings -> Editor -> **General ->** Code folding -> unckeck HTML 'style' attribute`